Reviewer suggestion - take note of who is proposing edits, even apparently legitimate ones
There's a certain user (deleted account 1) & (deleted account 2), who has been abusing the site for days now.
(I won't keep updating the link to his account, but by the time of this edit he is already in his third (at least) created user and still engaging in this behavior).
I noticed that he often makes edit proposals, some of them are reasonable, but most of them are either redundant or even mildly harmful.
It seems to me that given his record, it's clear his only intention with these edit proposals, is to gain rep, so that he can continue to abuse the site in more ways. I don't know how the internals of SE work of course, but I suspect getting your edit approved may be one of the markers that are antithetical to detecting a user as abusive.
So, the suggestion is simply, notice who is the user that's making the edit proposal. Especially for very small and inconsequential edits, that only fix a typo or two.
I personally rejected all his edit proposals with the reason "Spam or vandalism", simply because it's clear to me the intention behind these proposals is not to actually improve the site. Of course, ideally we want to judge an edit on its own merits, but I think here, in the case of an abusive user trying to "pump rep", an exception to this rule is in order. Please correct me if I am wrong.
For your reference, example of one of his edit proposals, this one got rejected, not all such others did, cf. this harmful one.

Users can gain at most 2k rep from edits, what is the concern here? Either the edits are okay (however minor) so accept them, or they aren't (reject them). It's not vandalism to contribute useful minor edits, and contributing to the site because you want to gain points is...kind of the entire point of gamification.

The concern is that it can be a way to evade a ban. But if that's unwarranted, no problem. As I said I'm not privy to how SE works about that kind of stuff, i.e. how a decision whether to ban a user goes through all the required approvals. But if having your edits approved doesn't matter in this regard, indeed there's no serious problem probably. Apart from the fact that sometimes this user mixes slight harmful parts of his edits along with harmless ones (I can point to examples).

That account no longer exists. But the user will probably create another one soon. I agree with you that this user is up to no good.

@Ghoster He already has, see edit above.

Instead of editing this meta question, please just flag for moderator attention if you see users evading bans. That's a completely separate issue to whether edits should be judged on their own merits.

The purpose of this post was not to ask whether edits should be judged on their own merits. I raised a certain suggestion, to promote awareness about how a certain user may be evading a ban, and that can also be relevant for similar cases in the future. I did consider raising a custom flag, but the issue with that is that much fewer moderating users will get to see it and hence the issue is likely to recur in the future. Anyway, if you still believe this suggestion is not a valid one, I'll delete this post.

The initial links to user's accounts do not work.

@ACuriousMind "Users can gain at most 2k rep from edits, what is the concern here?" that they would get enough reputation for upvoting and start engaging in voting fraud with their sockpuppet ring. This goal is not theoretical, but based on past activity of the same account. Does that answer your question?

@VLAZ users using sock puppets can just gain rep by up voting each others' posts, which yields rep much faster than the measly 2 rep per approved suggested edit. And again: if you suspect sock puppets or ban evasion, flag for moderator attention, as always. Moderators have tools to assess such problems more reliably than non-mod users.

@ACuriousMind they need to bootrstrap the sockpuppet ring, though. And that's literally what the user has been doing. I don't get why mods here on Physics are so dismissive of an issue that's been on their site for the better part of a week. A mod has even 1. approved a suggestion then immediately overridden them because the suggestion was bad. 2. interacted with a question asked by one sock, answered by another sock. Without that interaction being "nuke both accounts". A close and edit. I don't like telling mods how to do their jobs but the whole dismissive attitude is not great.

@ACuriousMind >  Moderators have tools to assess such problems more reliably than non-mod users. == In particular, they can see the ip addresses of sock puppets and can tell if they're coming from the same location or a known proxy like TOR. It for IP bounces around the country, that's also telling. == Did that happen in this case? And is that why both accounts were banned? It sounds to me like the system worked. The mods dug the troll out of the ground and disposed of it.

Same thing happened over Chemistry.SE: Edits by Anonymous user and approved by Community Bot. There is a separate troll who does this. Don't know if it is the same person.

@Ghoster You think he has stopped here. Just look over what's going in ELL.SE. He is just like a virus.

@VLAZ Hard agree on what you said. The trolls reportedly opens accounts within minutes after getting destroyed. Then targets bountied posts, vandalize the content, spams the comment section with question URL and irritating other users. A mod in chem.SE escalated the matter to the CMs and apparently they have done something to block this, but that didn't helped much. Mods then said what's done is done. They are as helpless as we are :(

Promoting to an answer:

Please just flag for moderator attention if you see users evading bans. That's a completely separate issue to whether edits should be judged on their own merits.


Thanks rob. Just to be 100% clear, for the sake of others reading this: flagging can only be done on questions/answers/comments, we can't flag users or their edit proposals. So any relevant post to which the abusive user is related should do in this case, cf. this mother-meta post.
